# Relative path in background url doesn't work when use css-modules

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, css-modules

I use react-react-app. I set `url: false`, and enable css-modules.

```
webpack.gonfig.dev.js(module/ rules): 
       {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          require.resolve("style-loader"),
          {
            loader: require.resolve("css-loader"),
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
              url: false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```

webpack.config.prod.js:

```
                {
                  loader: require.resolve("css-loader"),
                  options: {
                    importLoaders: 1,
                    modules: true,
                    url: false,
                    minimize: true,
                    sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap
                  }
                },
```

./index.css background doesn't work(**If I use absolute path it works**):

```
.whiteBoardMainSection {
background-image: url(../../assets/white-board-hospital.png);

}
```

import CSS

```
import styles from "./index.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

I shouldn't use `url: false` when url in node_modules throw err.I should add  `exclude: [/node_modules/]` in loader.

```
          {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          require.resolve("style-loader"),
          {
            loader: require.resolve("css-loader"),
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
            }
          }
        ],
        exclude: [/node_modules/]
      },
```